# Are there any ajax for PHP like zk or vaadin for java

Tags: php, ajax, frameworks

Are there any frameworks for php that follow the style of [vaadin](/questions/tagged/vaadin)?
In vaadin you can define web forms using java with touching javascript or any client scripting in swing style.

Answer (score 3):

All Ajax calls are made through Javascript - it is an absolute necessity, no way around it. Every framework you see doing Ajax, whether its in Java, .NET, or whatever - they are using Javascript. It may be generating the Javascript *for you* but it is still happening.

The [Prado framework](http://www.pradosoft.com/) handles all the Javascript lifting for you, so you can give that a shot. Its very .NET in style.

Answer (score 0):

I have been searching for something similar to Vaadin. The only framework I have found is [zk](/questions/tagged/zk), which works with Java.

Anyway, you can develop in ZK using any languages supported by the JVM.